# How to assign int number to double after decimal

Tags: java

Assume we have `int x = 4` and I want to assign `x` as a digit after the decimal in the following double number:

```
double value = 2.x;
```

so the `value` should be `2.4`

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Do you mean something like `value = x / 10.0 + 2.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple equation should help out

```
double value = 2 + x / 10.0;
```